# ¿Cómo puedo crear un diccionario de funciones?

Tags: swift2

Tengo una variable que lleno así:

```
var animation = [String: Void]() 
animation["a"] = animationA()
```

Pero al ejecutar mi código automáticamente se ejecuta la función `animationA()`, algo que quiero evitar, ya que lo que quiero es que cuando llame a la variable así: `animation["a"]()`, entonces se ejecute.

Y si en el arreglo coloco la variable de la siguiente manera `animation["a"] = animationA` me lanza error.

Alguien sabe si esto se puede hacer que mi función quede en una variable de un arreglo?

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

**Actualización 1**

Para un arreglo lo pude hacer, pero aun no para un diccionario:

```
//Así lo declaro
var array: [(Void -> Void)] = [] 
//Aquí asigno la función
array.append { () -> () in
            self.animationDefault()
        }
//Así ejecuto la función
array[0]()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de probar mil formas, pude hacerlo así:

```
var animation: [String: () -> ()] = [
    "a":
    {() -> () in self.animationA()}
]
animation["a"]!()
```